# php/sqlite3 - query - mixing data columns in search

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm working with Chinese - we have the characters and the pronunciations (pinyin).

I want to phrase a sqlite3 query in php that mixes characters and pinyin pronunciation for search.

EXAMPLE: let's say we want to find the Chinese word for `hello` --> 你好 | so our characters are: `你好` and (for the sake of example) pronunciation is `ni hao` (we'll omit tones for the sake of simplicity here).

DB would look a little like this:

|CHAR|PIN|

|你好|ni hao|

How could I mix and match CHAR & PIN column information in query? e.g.: how could I search `你hao` or `ni好` to find my 你好 entry?

my query at the moment looks like:

```
$results = $db->query( "SELECT CHS, PIN, DEF FROM MAIN WHERE CHS LIKE '%".$q."%' OR REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(PIN, '1',''),'2',''),'3',''), '4',''),' ','') LIKE '%".$q."%' OR PIN LIKE '%".$q."%' OR REPLACE(PIN, ' ','') LIKE '%".$q."%' OR REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(PIN, '1',''),'2',''),'3',''), '4','') LIKE '%".$q."%' ORDER BY PIN ASC");
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
```